# Grouping back the iterated groups on a DataFrame after performing an operation on them

Tags: pandas, group-by

I am iteraring over a DataFrame GroupBy object and performing an operation on each sub-dataframe. However, I want that these operations would be reflected back on the main DataFrame. For example, in this code:

```
for group, df_group in df_dates.groupby(["team", "metric"]): 
    team,  metric = group[0], group[1]
    default_serie = df_group.loc[(slice(None), "_DEFAULT", slice(None))].iloc[0]
    df_group = df_group.apply(lambda row: row.fillna(default_serie.T), axis=1)
```

I want the fillna operation performed over each `df_group` to be reflected on the main `df_dates`

Note: I am thinking of concatenating all the `df_group` outside the loop, but maybe is there a more elegant solution just inside the loop?